# Help me with this design please?

Tags: color

[image]
[image]

I need someone to design those two pictures. Size 250/250, High quality and same colors. GIMP IS A HEADACHE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for free work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People here are not extremely anxious to do something for those that do not show any own effort other than asking free service. That's why I design nothing, but return your stuff. In my house all borrowed stuff gets better, which in this case must be considered unfortunate.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If i have photoshop on my desktop i will make it in 3 mins. I'm not yet familiar with GIMP. GIMP is not even close to PS.

Comment: @user43474 these are complex patterns. A Photoshop master does not recreate them from scratch in 3 minutes. I even not tried, but used a fractal image enlargener and shaved off some noise. The leftmost shape maybe needs a 1 pixel wide full white ring to be added.